# Creating user defined function for firebird 2.5 with c++builder 2010

Tags: firebird, c++builder, user-defined-functions, udf, firebird2.5

I tried to create a simple user defined function (UDF) for Firebird 2.5 with C++ Builder 2010 but I don't manage to get it to work in Firebird.

1. Creating a DLL project with default setting in C++ Builder 2010.
2. Adding a unit with my example UDF including "ibase.h" and "ib_util.h":

   ```c
   extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) int __stdcall MYFUNC ( int i )  
   {  
        int result = 2 * i;  
        return result;  
   }
   ```
3. Building the DLL `FBUDFMBD.dll` in path `C:\Program Files (x86)\Firebird\Firebird_2_5\UDF`
4. Registering my UDF via IBExpert in a sample db with

   ```sql
   DECLARE EXTERNAL FUNCTION F_MYFUNC  
   INTEGER  
   RETURNS INTEGER 
   ENTRY_POINT 'MYFUNC' MODULE_NAME 'FBUDFMBD';
   ```
5. Calling the UDF with

   ```sql
   select F_MYFUNC( 3 ) from RDB$DATABASE;
   ```

   results in error message

   ```
   Invalid token.  
   invalid request BLR at offset 36.  
   function F_MYFUNC is not defined.  
   module name or entrypoint could not be found.
   ```

With the tool *GExperts - PE Information* I can see my UDF as DLL-Export `MYFUNC` ordinal `$1` and entry point `$1538`.

What I am doing wrong, Firebird can't register my DLL and its UDF correctly?

Is there anything in my DLL project to change regarding to default compiler options?

Comment: In my experience Firebird UDF question - usually - don't get a lot of answers here; you might want to consider asking your question on the Firebird-support mailinglist as well.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but I believe you need to remove the `extern "C" __declspec(dllexport)`, look for an example at https://github.com/FirebirdSQL/firebird/blob/8905e15435116bfac3abb30ae476d4812d1fe04b/src/extlib/ib_udf.cpp

Answer (score 2):

In Delphi, you can write `cdecl` and not `stdcall`

i.e

```
function ExisteBase(const aBase:PChar):Integer; cdecl;
```

Not

```
function ExisteBase(const aBase:PChar):Integer; stdcall;
```

Maybe on C++ `__cdecl`

I hope I helped in some

Answer (score 2):

Thanks a lot! I got it by your help.

**top 2:** Corrected C++-Code is:

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) int MYFUNC ( int * val )
{
   int result = 2 * *val;
   return result;
}
```

Pay attention to reference call of the input parameter.

**top 4:** Register the UDF in a firebird 2.5 db by

```
DECLARE EXTERNAL FUNCTION F_MYFUNC
INTEGER
RETURNS INTEGER BY VALUE
ENTRY_POINT '_MYFUNC' MODULE_NAME 'FBUDFMBD';
```

Pay attention to the leading underscore at the function name!

**top 5:** `select F_MYFUNC( 3 ) from RDB$DATABASE;` works really fine!

Comment: ..and now I go on with string parameters.